# What is the iPhone SMS database called in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, migration, sms

I need to migrate SMSs from an iPhone to an android, and I'd like to use solutions suggested [here](http://faked.org/isms2droid/), but I can't find the SMS db file (reportedly named 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28) in my unencrypted IOS6 backup.

What is the name / how can I identify the backup file?

Also relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/6904/6126

Comment: How many files are inside of the folder `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/<long_hex_string>/`?

Comment: :O 9013 files? oof, sounds like a bit of digging would be required. You're not jailbroken, I'm assuming

Comment: nope, not jailbroken.. I got a reply from Samsung Kies support: Kies eventually managed to import my SMSs from the iphone backup

if anyone knows of what kind of header the correct file has have, I'd still be curious to track the db down...

Answer (score 1):

Inside MobileSync/Backup/<your_long_hex_string>/ you should find this file "3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28"

Then open it with SQLite (e.g. SQLite Firefox plugin or "sqlite database browser"), and execute this SQL query:

```
select message.rowid,
    case when message.date=0 then null else datetime(message.date,  'unixepoch', 'localtime', '+31 years') end as sent,
    case when message.date_delivered=0 then null else datetime(message.date_delivered,  'unixepoch', 'localtime', '+31 years') end as delivered,    
case when message.date_read=0 then null else datetime(message.date_read,  'unixepoch', 'localtime', '+31 years') end as read, 
    case when h1.id is not null then h1.id else h2.id end as interlocutor,
    case when message.is_from_me then null else message.text end as to_me,
    case when message.is_from_me then message.text else null end as from_me,
attachment.filename as attach,
    case when message.error=0 then null else message.error end as error_code
    from message 
    left join handle h1 on message.handle_id=h1.rowid
    left join message_attachment_join on message_attachment_join.message_id=message.rowid
    left join attachment on message_attachment_join.attachment_id=attachment.rowid
    left join  chat_message_join on chat_message_join.message_id=message.rowid
    left join  chat_handle_join  on chat_handle_join.chat_id=chat_message_join.chat_id
    left join  handle h2 on chat_handle_join.handle_id=h2.rowid
order by message.roWID
```