# How can I copy/sync SMS messages between iPhones

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, sms

Is there a way (built in or 3rd party) to sync SMS messages (not iMessages) between 2 iPhones?

The scenario is that I have an old iPhone and a new iPhone that is already configured. Because of this I don't want to use the method of restoring a backup of the old iPhone onto the new iPhone. I'm primarily looking for a way to get the messages from the old phone onto the new phone, rather than keep them in sync.

One possible limitation is that the old iPhone is an iPhone 4 so is only running 7.1.2

Comment: Whole bunch of suggestions for export here - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6900/how-can-i-export-sms-text-messages-from-my-iphone?rq=1 - but no-one mentions import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The sandbox that contains app data prevents this as does the restore wiping instead of merging data functionality you are already aware of.

- You can back one phone up and restore it to the other.
- You can use iMessage to sync things in a forward direction ( new messages can sync well )
- You can use a tool like [Phoneview](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to [export all the messages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6900/how-can-i-export-sms-text-messages-from-my-iphone) from multiple devices and collate / combine / preserve them on your Mac.

Some [commercial transfer products and apps](http://cellebrite.com/Media/Default/Files/Lifecycle/Data-Sheets/P2P-Transfer-App-DataSheet.pdf) claim to do this, but I haven't seen anything consumer focused on the App Store to do this transfer or merge without jail breaking the device you want to do the "merge" - perhaps someone is more clever or informed and has a "yes" solution.

Comment: I'm interested in your second bullet point if you wouldn't mind clarifying that. Would I be able to move over my current text messages to my new device? I don't have any messages on the new phone, just don't want to reset the configuration and apps I've already set up

Comment: No joy there @MatthewSteeples from my experience. iMessage doesn't seem to reach backwards to sync data.  If you were to sign into iMessage on both devices, and try using them for a week you might get enough history that you might be happy moving forward with that solution