# How do I backup Messages from Macbook?

Tags: macos, messages

I want to delete all of my messages off my Macbook and iPhone but I'd like to back them up before I do so.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: They're stored in `~/Library/Messages`, but I think it's much easier to just decide if you want to actually delete them, instead of making a backup and trying to restore.

Comment: I have all of my text messages from 2011 on my phone and a bunch on my Macbook. I want to delete them. It just takes up too much space. Literally thousands upon thousands of messages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not that simple. The messages & database are 2 separate entities, & recombining later is not guaranteed. (On phone, can find links later)

Comment: See this for backup options - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6900/how-can-i-export-sms-text-messages-from-my-iphone note that none of them mention being able to later restore them...